# Can I use memcpy_s with ObjC on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memcpy

Is there any replacement for memcpy in iOS?
So far as I know, memcpy is not 'safe', and the suggested alternative is 'memcpy_s'

But, code fail to compile due to 'Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:' problem, after replacing memcpy with memcpy_s.

How can I fix this problem? How to setup the project settings? Any help will be appreciated.

Some code from AsyncSocket.m:

```
- (CFIndex)readIntoBuffer:(UInt8 *)buffer maxLength:(CFIndex)length
{
    if([_partialReadBuffer length] > 0)
    {
        // Determine the maximum amount of data to read
        CFIndex bytesToRead = MIN(length, [_partialReadBuffer length]);

        // Copy the bytes from the buffer
        memcpy(buffer, [_partialReadBuffer bytes], bytesToRead);

        // Remove the copied bytes from the buffer
        [_partialReadBuffer replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, bytesToRead) withBytes:NULL length:0];

        return bytesToRead;
    }
    else
    {
        return CFReadStreamRead(_theReadStream, buffer, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code where you use memcpy.

Comment: show some code here...

Comment: You can try using `strcpy()`.

Comment: @user3007735: `strcopy()` copies a NUL-terminated string, and cannot replace `memcpy`, which copies a given number of bytes.

Comment: I wonder whether __builtin___memcpy_chk is the safe one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as I know, memcpy is not 'safe'

That's not true as-is. In contrast with some really unsafe stdlib functions, it is only "not safe" if you can't use it. `memcpy()` takes a buffer length as its third argument, so you don't risk buffer overflows; you can also check for the source and target pointers in order to avoid dereferencing `NULL`, etc.

`memcpy_s()` is a Microsoft extension, and a such, it's only available on Windows (fortunately). If you need `memcpy()`, then use it, and don't try to replace standard functions with vendor-specific stuff (especially not if that vendor is Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own version following what Microsoft did with memcpy_s. Just look at their code.

Comment: Please either provide sample code, a bullet list of points or give a summary of memcpy